# MongoDB nesting ancestor elements into parent

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a number of comments made on a post.

```
[id: 10] Root comment
|
|-- [id: 11] Reply to root
|   |
|   |-- [id: 12] Reply to reply to root
|       |
|       |-- [id: 13] Bottom comment in this chain
|
|-- [id: 19] Another reply to root
```

Any one comment in a chain of replies contains the full path back to the root comment.

The "bottom comment in this chain" will have its parents array looking like this:

```
{
  ...
  parents: [10, 11, 12, 13]
  ...
}
```

I'd like to get the parent comment message with replies nested into it as shown below.

```
{
    "_id": "10",
    "postId": "333"
    "parents": ["11","12","13"],
    ...
}
```

I have the following `aggregate` query which **produces incorrect results** where the parent comment id i.e. 10 is included in the results.

I'm getting the parent element using the `match` clause and nest the reply comments using `lookup`.

```
db.comments.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { $and: [
                { "postId": "333" },
                { "parents": { $size: 1 } }
            ]}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "comments",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "parents",
                pipeline: [{ $sort: { "createdAt": 1 }}],
                as: "replies"
            }
        },
    {
        $sort: { "createdAt": -1 }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried $graphLookup?

Comment: @Joe Just tried it, but I can't get it exclude the "Root comment" id: 10 from results.

Comment: I need to remove the first element from `replies` array field.

Comment: @AliCelebi Hey I am working on same: https://mongoplayground.net/p/o4uYW0hA4fI
How did you manage to organise the replies so it can rendered on UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to filter the parent comment, in another stage, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      postId: 333,
      parents: {
        "$size": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$parents",
      "connectFromField": "parents",
      "connectToField": "parents",
      "as": "replies",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "replies": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$replies",
          "as": "item",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              {
                "$size": "$$item.parents"
              },
              {
                "$size": "$parents"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G7NSlsuZNLY)